# Use lambda expression to count the elements that I'm interested in Python

Tags: python, lambda

Can I use lambda expression to count the elements that I'm interested?
For example, when I need to count the elements in a list that is more than two, I tried this code which returns 0.

```
x = [1,2,3]
x.count(lambda x: x > 2)
```

Comment: This code doesn't return anything. You have a syntax error. Don't type from memory, copy/paste code that demonstrably works.

Comment: Why do you want to use `lambda`s?

Comment: Your code counts how often this particular lambda object is in the list.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

Note: "more than" is `>` ... `=>` is not a valid operator.

Try `sum(y > 2 for y in x)`

Or, as suggested by [@Jochen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7549525/use-lambda-expression-to-count-the-elements-that-im-interested-in-python#comment9149564_7549544), to guard against non-conventional nth-party classes, use this:

`sum(1 for y in x if y > 2)`

Comment: Summing booleans. Nice. +1 for demonstrating that `lambda` is not necessary.

Comment: or `sum(1 for y in x if y > 2)`

Comment: @TokenMacGuy: or it could be decimal, or rational, or some weird DIY class; whatever y is, surely `y > 2` should not run amok. I don't see the point of `float(y)`. Yes, some badass class could define comparison operators that return neither `True` nor `1` for truthy results -- in which case, the suggestion of @Jochen [Thanks!] avoids the explicit `bool()`

Comment: `sum(1 for y in x if y > 2)` is IMHO the best and most Pythonic answer.

Answer (score 21):

You can try any of the following

```
len([y for y in x if y > 2])
```

or

```
len(filter(lambda y: y > 2, x))
```

or the nicer

```
sum( y > 2 for y in x )
```

Comment: OP wanted "more than two", not "more than or equal to two".

Comment: I tried the second option. But it says 'filter' has no len.

Comment: @vijayst This answer is from 2011 and thus for Python 2.7. `filter` returns a generator in Python 3.x meaning that suggested method is no longer applicable.

Answer (score 4):

```py
from functools import reduce

x = [1,2,3]
reduce(lambda a,i: a+1 if (i>2) else a, x, 0)
```

This will not create a new list. `a` is the accumulator variable, `i` is the item from the list, and the `0` at the end is the initial value of the accumulator.