# Counting number of ocurrences in a list of objects

Tags: python

Having:

```
class Foo:
   def __init__(self, a, b):
       self.a = a 
       self.b = b
```

and a list like:

```
l = [Foo(1, 2), Foo(1, 3), Foo(1, 4), Foo(1, 10)]
```

If I want to count the number of objects having a == 1, I do

```
>>> count_a = len([o for o in l if o.a == 1]) 
>>> assert count_a == 4
```

It is not a function in the library to allow me to execute somthing like:

```
>>> from operator import attrgetter
>>> count(l, key=attrgetter('a'))
4
```

Comment: This is basically the same as [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7549525/use-lambda-expression-to-count-the-elements-that-im-interested-in-python) looks like Python needs to borrow [`std::count_if`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/count) from C++

Comment: You probably want to change the signature of `count` to allow for a numeric value to compare the field value against it.

Comment: You could also use `getattr(obj, attr)` if your attribute name is variable

Comment: I think you are missing an argument in your desired function, how it is going to know that o.a == 1

Comment: I think it is a stupid question. Sorry to waste your time.

Comment: Why do you say that? It is a good, well written question. It just happens to been asked already...

Comment: I thought that may be should be a faster way to count than the list comprehension or sum and generator, hiding details in the library or something like that .. It is not that I was asking how to write a hypothetic function. I mean I was trying to leverage and not reinvent the wheel.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `sum` and a generator:

```
sum(1 for o in l if o.a==1)
```

output: `4`

*NB. `sum(o.a == 1 for o in l)` would also work but this is twice slower, presumably as all items reach and are computed by `sum`*

Comment: That is basically the same, in spirit, to their list comprehension and I do not feel addresses their primary question which I interpret as "is there a library function to count from a container using a lambda to specify a predicate"

Comment: This is not a comprehension, this is a sequence generator.

Comment: It can also be written more succinctly as `sum(o.a == 1 for o in l)`

Comment: @Cory I feel it is quite different in the sense that you don't have to build and store a list of potentially big objects. Here there is just a generator.

Comment: @DmitriChubarov yes but I'm not sure it would be faster, I don't know the code of sum, but if this passes 0/False to sum then there are unnecessary operations

Comment: @Tomerikoo I just compared `sum(condition for object in list)` and `sum(1 for object in list if condition)` and the second is ~2 times faster, so the slightly shorter code is not worth it ;)

Comment: That's a very interesting conclusion. Thank you. It makes sense thinking about it: the boolean need to be converted to int and summed, while in your approach the condition is only checked and 1is always added